# combine 2 separate complex queries

Tags: sql, mysqli, subquery, union

I recently built an online game that is still in developing mode. Using `mysqli` I query a table to get the current user's rank. This is based on position within table, ordered by score.

The problem is I have two separate rank positions to get and I currently do this in two separate queries, could someone point me in the right direction as to combine these.

**Current setup**

```
$sql="SELECT * from 
(
SELECT mode1_score, name, id, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank 
FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY mode1_score DESC
) users
order by mode1_score DESC";

//code to output rank here for game mode 1

// new query
$sql="SELECT * from 
(
SELECT mode2_score, name, id, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank 
FROM users, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY mode2_score DESC
) users
order by mode2_score DESC";

//code to output rank here for game mode 2
```

Data Structure

Table name = `users`

```
id       |  name  |  mode1_score  |  mode2_score
-------------------------------------------------
1233345     foo         0              1200
3454535     boo        847             1143
2344443     doo        1127            687
```

Comment: Use an `INNER JOIN` for both tables, **aliases** for the rows you want to retrieve and `ORDER BY` both fields in order.

Are the two tables linked by a key?

Comment: @Danny They use the same table, it's just that the score modes are in 2 separate columns

Comment: if you have a `mode1_score` value will you also have a `mode2_score` value for a single record?  or, will one be null/zero?

Comment: @StevenPHP allright, then i need a chance to understand what you are achieving here

Comment: @Linger either score could be 0 up to 1500

Comment: @StevenPHP, within the same record, right?

Comment: @Linger I've updated my question with the data structure within the table. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is doing something like the below query.  What I am doing is setting a constant that identifies the mode score, then I wrap that query and order by the mode constant first and the actual score second.  Then in your code you know that `ModeConst` of `1` is for the `mode1_score` and a `ModeConst` of `2` is for the `mode2_score`.

The `mode_score` will be ordered like you want since the constant is ordered first.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 AS ModeConst, mode1_score AS ModeScore, name, id, @r := @r + 1 as rank 
  FROM users, (SELECT @r := 0) r
  ORDER BY mode1_score DESC 
) a
UNION 
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT 2 AS ModeConst, mode2_score AS ModeScore, name, id, @s := @s + 1 as rank 
  FROM users, (SELECT @s := 0) s
  ORDER BY mode2_score DESC
) b
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Which would produce the following results:

[image]

Your code would handle whatever you have for:

```
//code to output rank here for game mode 1
```

Then once the first `ModeConst` with a value of `2` is found you would start and finish executing whatever you have for:

```
//code to output rank here for game mode 2
```

[**SQL Fiddle Sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bff78/41/0)

Comment: Thanks. This is causing an error. I get only a blank page. I have enabled error output but nothing is displaying.

Comment: **@StevenPHP**, I added an SQL Fiddle sample to my answer to show that the query does work.  Do you have a typo somewhere?  Are you using the query exactly as I have it?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, it makes it so much easier to visualise. The returned example based on the current data structure would be `foo` is Rank 1 for `mode1_score` and Rank 3 for `mode2_score`. The fiddle does not return those values as far as I can see?

Comment: Don't you mean `foo` should be Rank 1 for `mode2_score` since it is in descending order?  What do you use the rank for?

Comment: Typo, sorry - In my comment I meant to write `doo` not `foo`.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Is that what you are after?  I added a screenshot of the results just in case SQL Fiddle is down at any particular time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm! I really need to get some training on `union` and `join` etc when it comes to SQL. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: **@StevenPHP**, actually SQL Fiddle is a great resource to try different queries out.  Combine that with what you can find searching Google and SO and you should be able to answer most of your question yourself.  That's what I did to answer this question.